# Online check in with group. How will the boarding passes be distributed?

Tags: europe, transavia

I will be travelling with a group of 8, all travelling with hand luggage only. I booked the tickets for the full party. The order confirmation from Transavia said I can check in online and my boarding pass will be on my phone.

Since I'm travelling with a group of people, **will I get all boarding passes on my phone?**

If so, is there a way around this? I don't want to be responsible for the rest of the group's boarding passes.

Transavia gave me vague information when contacting;

> If you feel insecure about the online check-in process, please check
>   in using a counter at Schiphol. Make sure you arrive at the airport on time to avoid missing your flight due to long wait times.

If checking in at the counter is the only option, do we need to be at the counter at the same time? Part of the group has a tendency to run late.

Comment: It's been a few months since my last flight with Transavia but I think you can download boarding passes as often as you like (using the booking code, last name and date of the flight). Everybody should therefore be able to install the Transavia app and get them on their own phone. You might also be able to get them as PDF or PNG files you could send around. Alternatively, you can choose the “print at home option” and print boarding passes for everybody.

Comment: Every flight I've taken (none with a group, though) required a name on the boarding pass to match the holder's ID and the photo on the ID to match the face.

Comment: @WGroleau I happened to fly without having provided ANY document (excluding boarding pass, of course). No one just asked me to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When boarding passes are delivered to your phone, it is usually done as either a text message or email with an image of your boarding pass or barcode on it. Whenever I have done this there is an option to send each boarding pass to a different email or phone number. So all you would need to do is collect an email or phone number for each person and get the pass sent to them. Alternatively if you get all the passes sent to you you can forward the message to the right person.

There are almost always alternatives to having the boarding pass on a phone. Generally there is an option to print them yourself if you check in online. You could then hand out the paper ones to your group. And finally there is the option to check in at the airport and have counter staff hand out passes. This can be done even if you have already checked in online.